# Menu com links quebrados no IOS (Safari)

Tags: html, css, mobile, front-end, mobile-safari

Desenvolvi um projeto de site onde a primeira tela é um menu que redireciona para outras telas, quando tésto o responsivo funciona normal, mas quando tento abrir no meu *iPhone* é exibido um texto simples e a estilização muda um pouco. Em dispositivos android funciona normalmente.

Acho que foi algo que fiz de errado dentro dos medias query's, tenho que fazer algo no html para otimizar nos dispositivos *iPhone*?

```css
/*fontes*/

@font-face {
  font-family: principal;
  src: url(../_fonts/GothamLight.ttf);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: caminhos;
  src: url(../_fonts/GothamBook.ttf);
}


/*corpo do site*/

body {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.705);
  background-image: url(../_imagens/foto-fundotext.png);
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 90px;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

.logo {
  margin-bottom: -19vh;
  width: 40vh;
}

.global {
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.container img {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0vh;
}


/*Menu inicial*/

nav {
  padding-top: 0px;
}

a.leg {
  font-family: caminhos;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  list-style: none;
}

li:hover {
  transform: scale(1.04);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  align-items: center;
}

a.leg:hover {
  transform: scale(1.0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgb(91, 59, 133);
  align-items: center;
  color: rgb(240, 203, 232);
}


/*redes*/

.icones {
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.icones {
  padding-top: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.icones img {
  padding: 15px;
  align-items: center;
  width: 35px;
}

.icones img:hover {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  padding-bottom: 11px;
}

#menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 5vh;
  margin-bottom: 6vh;
}

#menu p {
  margin: 20px 0 0 0 !important;
  font-size: 1px;
}

p {
  font-size: 5pt;
}

@media (max-width: 425px) {
  body {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.705);
    background-image: url(../_imagens/foto-fundo-cell2.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .global {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 15vh !important;
    margin-left: 8vw;
    width: 80vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .container {
    width: 50vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  #menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 0vh;
  }
  .logo {
    margin-bottom: -18vh !important;
    margin-top: -5vh;
    width: 5vh;
  }
  /*Menu inicial*/
  nav {
    padding-top: 20px;
  }
  a.leg {
    font-family: caminhos;
    font-size: 2vh;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: lighter;
  }
  li {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    list-style: none;
  }
  li:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    align-items: center;
  }
  a.leg:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px rgb(214, 183, 255);
    align-items: center;
  }
  /*redes*/
  .icones {
    padding-top: 0px;
  }
  .icones img {
    width: 25px;
    padding: 10px;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .barra img {
    width: 35vh;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .global {
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 1vh;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .logo {
    margin-bottom: -15vh;
    width: 40vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./_css/style-tela-1.css" />
  <link rel="icon" href="/_imagens/icone-aolado-da-pagina.png">
  <title>Marina Leite</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="global">
    <img class="logo" src="./_imagens/Marina-Leite.png">

    <div class="container">

      <div class="barra">
        <img src="./_imagens/Barrafina.png">
      </div>
      <div id="menu">

        <p><span><a href="./legisladora.html" class="leg">Legisladora</a></span></p>
        <p><span><a href="./engenheira.html" class="leg">Engenheira</a></span></p>
        <p><span><a href="./campanha2020.html" class="leg">Campanha de 2020</a></span></p>
        <p><span><a href="./proposta.html" class="leg">Minhas Propostas </a></span></p>

      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="barra">
      <img src="./_imagens/Barrafina.png">
    </div>
    <div class="icones">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/yannemarinaof" target="_blank"> <img src="./_imagens/Mask group-1.png"></a>

      <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=55558897949437" target="_blank"> <img src="./_imagens/Mask group-2.png"> </a>

      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/yannemarina/" target="_blank"> <img src="./_imagens/Mask group.png"></a>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -3):

A questão ai não é link quebrado, e sim problema com renderização de fonte. Acontece que o Safari, se eu não estiver equivocado, tem umas particularidades com renderização de fonte, de forma que é recomendável disponibilizar fonte no formato .svg pro sistema iOS ou MAC. Outro ponto importante seria usar formato mais moderno de fonte pra web que .ttf, como .woff por exemplo.

Vamos lá:

1 - Primeiro, pegar sua fonte .ttf e converter pra .svg, e se tu puder .woff também, em alguma plataforma de conversão de fontes como https://convertio.co/pt/ttf-svg/

2 - E  disponibilizar a versão .svg dela no seu @font-face, e .woff ou .woff2 também se tiver disponível. O seu @font-face deve ficar da seguinte forma com mais de uma opção de fonte disponível:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: nome-da-fonte;
  src: url(../_fonts/nome-do-arquivo-de-fonte.ttf);
  src: url(../_fonts/nome-do-arquivo-de-fonte.svg) format('svg'),
       url(../_fonts/nome-do-arquivo-de-fonte.woff) format('woff');
}
```

Testa e me avisa se funcionou